# Connecting to multiple collections in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We have multiple collections (one for master data, one for transactional data) for Cosmos DB. I need to connect to the multiple collections in my web application. Since we started with a single collection, I had created a singleton instance of the DocumentDB connection. Now, we are envisioning multiple collections. Would it be a right practice to have multiple singleton connections per collection or is there a better way I could handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need separate Cosmos DB Client for every collection, See below code...

```
private static DocumentClient client = GetDatabaseClient();

public static void Run(string myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
var master data = GetMasterData("124",log);
}

private static string GetMasterData(string serialNumber, TraceWriter log)
{

    var query = new SqlQuerySpec("select c.AssetType FROM c where c.AppName = 'AppName' and c.Device[0].SerialNumber=@SerialNumber",
           new SqlParameterCollection(new SqlParameter[] {
               new SqlParameter { Name = "@SerialNumber", Value = serialNumber }
           }));

    JObject result = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(
                 UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, masterCollectionId), query).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
    return result["AssetType"]?.Value<string>();

}

private static DocumentClient GetDatabaseClient()
{
DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(
new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cosmos_endpoint"]),
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cosmos_key"]);
return documentClient;
}
```

Check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to.

Your singleton has a selflink in the form of a URI for the collection you are querying or doing other operations on. You could just make the name of the collection a parameter and then use the `UriFactory` of the SDK, which needs the database id and collection id (name), to generate the selflink of the collection you want to query.

However depending on the load you are expecting, it might be a better idea to split them but it comes down to your singleton implementation. If it is a thread safe one then others might have to wait for a long operation to finish before they operate.